# if f and g are continuous, then g∘f is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

if $f$ and $g$ are continuous, then $g \circ f$ is continuous

how can we prove that by using this definition of continuous:

$f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be continuous if for each open subset $V$ of $\mathbb{R}$ , $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$

please,help me with that how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You assume $f$ and $g$ are continuous, so for any open subsets $U,V$ of $\mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}(U)$ and $g^{-1}(V)$ are open.

Take an open subset $V$ of $\mathbb{R}$ and try to show $(g\circ f)^{-1}(V)$ is open. Hint: You can take one inverse image at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Using your notation, we have that $g \circ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and let $V$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. We want to show that 
$$(g \circ f)^{-1}(V)$$ 
is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Note that $(g \circ f)^{-1} = f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$. Hence we have that 
$$(g \circ f)^{-1}(V) = f^{-1}(g^{-1}(V)).$$
Since $g$ is continuous, we have that $g^{-1}(V)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Let us denote $U = g^{-1}(V)$. Since $U$ is open and $f$ is continuous, we know that $f^{-1}(U)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and hence we have shown that 
$$ f^{-1}(U) = f^{-1}(g^{-1}(V)) = (g \circ f)^{-1}(V) $$
is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$, which proves that $g \circ f$ is a continuous function.